# What are some methods to disable or correct for backward browsing in web apps?

Tags: php, javascript

Some web apps *'by design*'  don't function well when user's hit the back button in the middle of a procedure.  What are some ways to disable or correct for users hitting the back button in vulnerable app sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several javascript frameworks out there that help with this problem.

Ext JS is one that I know of for sure.

Here is a discussion about other frameworks regarding this issue:
http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=673

Comment: No problem. I'm sorry I can't give you more details about it... I just remembered reading about it!

Answer (score 1):

Web applications that don't function when the user hits the back button are badly designed. Users expect the back button to work, and usually all attempts to disable this function greatly annoy the users. So I advise against any such plans and can only recommend to make the application work with the back button.

Comment: Great answer Sebastian.  I don't necessarily want to disable the back-button.  Just wanted to know some common techniques in addressing the problem.